# How do I make this Youtube Video clickable (css + z-index)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the Youtube video to be a background wallpaper, but I still want it to be interactive. i.e. the user can pause the video by clicking on it.

Right now, I've set the iframe to be z-index of -99.  For some reason,I can't click on it! After inspecting it with Firebug, it seems that **body** covers the iframe.  (The only way to click on it is if you scroll down to the bottom, where body ends and the iframe is revealed.

Is there any way to make this iframe clickable without changing everything's else around? Right now, my main website, things have default z-indexes. I don't want to make them all to be "2" just so I can make the iframe "1"

Note: You can't stick this code in jsfiddle. (It won't work because of jsfiddle's frame.)

```
<style>
    body{
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    iframe{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        z-index:-99;
    }
    .go{
        color:#fff;
        position:relative;
        margin-top:50px;

    }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<iframe id='youtube_bg' class="youtube-player" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lUjWJSnGVB0?wmode=opaque&autohide=1&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0">&lt;br /&gt;</iframe>


<div class="go">
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
<h1>hahaihaahahaha</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said you have to change the z-index of every child of body except the iframe.

```
body > * {
z-index : 2 !important;
}

#youtube_bg {
z-index : 1;
}
```

Or you change the z-index of body and html to -1, the iframe to 0 and the content keeps at 1 or auto.

```
html, body {
z-index : -1;
}
#yotube_bg {
z-index : 0;
}
```

For later edits of the css the second solution would be better