# Youtube Background video

Tags: html, css

i have a site, the index is a background video of youtube.

I have this code

```
 <div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" 
    src="https://youtube.com/embed/ID?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

I add the styles commands in the div, and works perfect. But this style will not let me pause the video.

Any Help? Thanks

Comment: If the `z-index` is set to a lower number than everything else on the page, those other things on the page will essentially cover the video (and therefore, the pause button) making it inaccessible/unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your iFrame is covered by the other elements in the page. It won't get the clicks you do.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8887376/4185234) answer suggests two methods.

> Like you said you have to change the z-index of every child of body
>   except the iframe.

```
body > * {
z-index : 2 !important;
}

#youtube_bg {
z-index : 1;
}
```

> Or you change the z-index of body and html to -1, the iframe to 0 and
>   the content keeps at 1 or auto.

```
html, body {
z-index : -1;
}
#yotube_bg {
z-index : 0;
}
```